# App version doesn't appear in FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) Console

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created a new version of my iOS app. All previous versions use FCM and I have no problem with this. Now I'm trying to test the push notifications but this new version doesn't appear in FCM Console, so I can't test it. I can see the 15 previous versions, but not the new one. 
I have experienced the same issue with an Android app, also with the same number of versions (15).

After this, I have looked at all my apps in FCM and none of them have more than 15 versions. In fact, some of them have exactly 15 versions.

Is there any limit in the number of app versions that FCM can handle? How can I expand this limit or how can I delete older versions from FCM Console? Or does someone have another explanation for this issue?

[15 versions of the app in FCM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3DDu.png)

Comment: *firebaser here* "Is there any limit in the number of app versions that FCM can handle?" I don't think there is a limit on the number of app versions, and even if there is I doubt it'd be that low. I'm wondering if this is an issue in the UI. Does the new version (that doesn't show up in the console) receive a message that you send to all versions?